# int[][] somehow not reintializing

Tags: java, arrays

I am essentially trying to make a program that will decide where the best place to put a piece (tetris-esque pieces) on a 10x10 grid. I determine the best place in a given game state by the amount of empty spaces (more is better). Full rows and columns clear. My method insertPiece(grid,piece,x,y) seems to be mutating the grid variable in my findBestMove method as it next iteration contains the piece.

```
 public static int[][] findBestMove(int[][] grid,Piece piece){
    int mostEmpty = 0;
    int bestX = 0;
    int bestY = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<grid.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<grid[i].length;j++){
            if(isPlaceable(grid,piece,i,j)){


                int[][] temp = insertPiece(grid,piece,i,j); 

                if(countEmpty(temp)>mostEmpty){
                    bestX = i;
                    bestY = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int[][] temp = insertPiece(grid,piece,bestX,bestY);
    return clearRows(temp);



}
public static int[][] insertPiece(int[][] grid, Piece piece, int x, int y){

    printGrid(grid);
    int[][] pieceGrid = piece.getGrid();

    for(int i=0;i<pieceGrid.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<pieceGrid[i].length;j++){
            try {
                if (grid[i + x][j + y] < pieceGrid[i][j]) {
                    grid[i + x][j + y] = pieceGrid[i][j];
                } else if (grid[i + x][j + y] == 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
               // break;
            }


        }
    }
    printGrid(grid);


    return grid;

}
```

This is what the final print looks like

```
0000000000
0100100100
1111111110
0100100100
1111111110
0100100100
1111111110
0100100100
1111111110
0000000000
```

This is the piece im inserting

```
int[][] gridPyramid = {{0,0,0},
                       {0,1,0},
                       {1,1,1}};
```

I left out large chunks of code to avoid cluttering the post, let me know if you need any clarification

Answer (score 0):

You are actually changing the grid in:

```
grid[i + x][j + y] = pieceGrid[i][j];
```

Comment: shouldn't that be changing the local version of grid in insertPiece and not the one in findBestMove?

Comment: Java passes object references by value to method arguments, so no. There's no local copy of the array. There's a local copy of a the reference to 'grid`. Basically two pointers to the same array.

Comment: do you have a suggestion on how to fix this then?